# Meaning of もの in this song

Tags: grammar

最近、小松未歩という歌手の「謎」という歌をよく聞きます。

全体の意味は(想像のもとで)たぶんわかりやすいですが、1行目の歌詞が何回聞いても読んでもわかりません。

> この世であなたの愛を手にいれる**もの**
>
> 踊るライト見つめて忘れない ahh 謎が解けてゆく

「手にいれたいもの」のほうがよくないですか。
なぜこんなところで「もの」を使いましたか。どういう意味でしょうか。

歌詞: http://www.kasi-time.com/item-14804.html

ビデオ: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=sQnznXS_MJs

Answer (score 5):

I know this song since my childhood, but have never tried to think about the lyrics seriously...

> この世であなたの愛を手に入れるもの

I interpret this as "the thing with which one can obtain your love." Since this is a song about 謎 (mystery), one may translate this less literally as "the key to obtain your love". I think this もの is 物 (="a thing"). Grammatically similar expressions include:

> - 字を書くもの something to write characters with (i.e., a pen)
> - [いい夢を見られる道具](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/46532/5010) a device with which one can see a good dream

---

Let's consider other possibilities of もの.

Can it be 者 (="person")? If it were 者, the sentence would mean "the person who wants to obtain your love". But 者 is [a fairly stiff word](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/21536/5010) and I don't expect 者 used like this in a love song.

Can it be the sentence-end particle [もの](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/219750/meaning/m0u/), which is often colloquially changed to もん? Then the sentence would mean something like "You know, I'm gonna obtain your love!" At least it's grammatical, and this sounds like she is determined to do so. However, this もの [sounds a bit childish](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/32322/5010), and does not match the context that follows. The person in the song is wondering and hesitating throughout the lyrics. She is not naively trying to be loved by あなた; she is trying to solve the mystery of love in a rather objective manner. (In addition, I feel the melody and the way of singing show that this is not a sentence-end particle もの, but I cannot explain this logically.)

I feel 「手に入れたいもの」 is not natural because what she is talking about in the first line is 謎, not her personal desire.

---

**EDIT:** Let me add two other reasons why I think this もの is *not* 者. (1) 者 is almost always written in kanji. There is no reason for using hiragana for 者 here. (2) Again, context. There are only あなた and 私 in this song. There is no third person, and "who will be the one who obtains your love" is not the topic of this song. The motif of this song, 謎, which she struggles to solve, is the difficult relationship that exists only between あなた and 私.

Comment: 解釈が分かれるところなのでupvoteはしませんが私自身も「物」だと思います。また、「あなた」は探偵であり探偵は謎を愛するので愛を手に入れる主体を「もの＝謎」と単純に解釈してもいいと思います。

Comment: 90年代のアニメの主題歌はアニメ自体とほぼ関係ないタイアップ曲がほとんどだったので、あまりコナンのストーリー自体と絡めて‌​語るのは良くない気はします。ただ、これだ‌​け何度もサビで繰り返されているので、この曲の冒頭部分は明らかに曲のモチーフである『​謎』を‌​指しています。なのでこの歌詞全体として『​謎』とは何のことなのかを理解するのは重要‌​だと思います。この曲は、恋のライバルと競‌​ったり陽気に愛を歌ったりする曲ではありません。「わたし」と「あなた」との関係の中のみで‌​、「涙あふれ」たり心が「傷」んだり「見失」ったり「迷」っ‌​たりしている曲です。その暗中模索感が『​謎』の正体だ‌​と思います。なので、「誰が愛を手に入れる‌​のか／私こそが愛を手に入れるのだ」と何度‌​も歌う理由はなくて、むしろ「何によって／‌​どうすればあなたの愛を手に入れられるのか‌​、何が解決の鍵（手がかり）なのか」と、テ‌​ーマに即して歌っていると解釈するのが自然だと思います。「この世であなたの愛を手に入れる鍵」であればわかりやすかったのですが。

Answer (score 2):

> 「この世{よ}であなたの愛{あい}を手{て}にいれるもの」

鋭い質問をされますね。

私見ですが、この「もの」は女性的な終助詞の「もの」ではないかと思います。それ以外の解釈は不自然であると考えます。この終助詞「もの」は軽い決意・強調を表します。

（日本語学習者のみなさんに、逆の意味で捉えられるといけませんので、念のために言いますと、「～～ではない**か**と思う」は「～～だと思う」と同じ意味になります。要するに、私は既に結論を述べています。）

他の可能性について考えてみましょう。

まず、「物{もの}」ではないことは文法的に明らかです。対象物が「あなたの愛」であると明確に述べられているからです。

続いて、「者{もの}」でもなさそうです。この曲の歌詞のスタイルからして、「人」という意味で「者」を使用する可能性は基本的にゼロかと思います。「者」では堅苦しく、曲のイメージに合わないからです。使うなら「人」とか「誰か」あたりでしょう。

「この世であなたの愛を手にいれるもの」の一行が歌詞のアタマに来ていることも重要です。なんらかのメッセージをアタマでいきなり述べてしまうのは、歌謡曲ではよくある手法です。「生きている間にあなたの愛を手に入れたい」という願望がこの曲のテーマそのものです。

さらに歌詞の後半で、「謎めくあなたの愛を手に入れた**とき**」という部分がありますが、これは「仮定」を表しています。実際にそれを手に入れた時、「世界は生まれ変わる　目覚めたら　ahh  無限に広がる」と言っています。願望が現実になるかもしれないという、ストーリーの展開がここに見られます。

Answer (score 2):

> この世であなたの愛を手にいれるもの

というのは

> The one who attains your love in this world

と解釈されるべきだと思います。つまり、「もの」=「[者](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/219748/meaning/m0u/)」です。

理由は二つあります。

1. 「この世で」と呼応する

   「この世で」という表現が出てくる時は、たいてい「最も／一番～〔名詞〕」「唯一／数少ない～〔名詞〕」という意味の文章が続くことが期待されます。この〔名詞〕は修飾部の「この世で～」の意味上の主語であることが普通です。ここでは「最も」や「唯一」などという言葉は出てきませんが、ニュアンスとしては「たった一人」という気持ちがこめられていると思います。
2. 『[名探偵コナン](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%90%8D%E6%8E%A2%E5%81%B5%E3%82%B3%E3%83%8A%E3%83%B3)』の主題歌

   「者」という形式名詞は堅い表現で、謙譲語として以外は、法律や哲学の文章でしかあまり聞かない言葉です。ただ、この曲は『名探偵コナン』という推理アニメのオープニングテーマ**にするため**に作られた曲です。アニメの内容は、探偵として天才的な推理力で論理的に事件の犯人や真実を明らかにしていくというものなので、そのアニメが始まる最初のフレーズに用いるにはインパクトがありふさわしい表現だと思います。

Answer (score 1):

> あなたの愛{あい}を手{て}にいれる**もの**

歌詞{かし}全体{ぜんたい}を考{かんが}えると、「あなたの愛{あい}を手{て}にいれるものは」で使{つか}われる「もの」は、「者{もの}（＝人{ひと}）」という意味{いみ}でしょう。

「あなたの愛{あい}を手{て}に入れる者{もの}」とは、「あなたが愛{あい}する人{ひと}」です。その人{ひと}は私{わたし}であって欲{ほし}しい、そしてその確率{かくりつ}はどんどん高{たか}まっているがまだ確{たし}かでない。早{はや}く、私{わたし}だけにあなたの愛{あい}を向{む}けてくださいという願{ねが}いのこもった歌詞{かし}です。

「もの」 is 「者{もの}」which means a person when I think about the whole lyrics.
A person getting his love is the person whom he loves. I wish the person were me and the probability is increasing steadily but not sure yet. This is a lyric that is full of the wish to turn his love only to me quickly.